# JQuery with Forms

Tags: jquery

### I have the following HTML:

```
<form class="lala">
<input type="text" id="textv" value="Text 1" size="5">
<input type="submit" value="Go!"></form>

<form class="lala"><input type="text" id="textv" value="Text 2" size="5"><input type="submit" value="Go!"></form>
```

### Now I have the following JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".lala").submit(function() {
        alert($("#textv").val());
});
```

Of course this is not working (I know I shouldn't use duplicate IDs) , but how can I show an alert of the text value where the corresponding submit button was clicked?

Thanks,
Joel

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $("form.lala").submit(function(){
        alert($(this).find(":text:last").val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".lala").submit(function(){
      alert($("#textv").val());
      return false;
});
}
```

Comment: I think you might have misread the question. How do you ensure that the selector finds the right `#textv` when there are two such elements in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there in the first place. Just give ur selector a context of the submitted form. Note the addition of ",this":

```
$(function() {
    $('.lala').submit(function() {
        alert($('#textv',this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

<del>You should be able to access the `<input type="text">` which is placed just before the `<input type="submit">` in the markup, using the [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) function:</del>

I misread your original jQuery snippet, and thought you where handling the `click` event on the button, rather than the `submit` event on the form. Your problem should be solvable by using the overload of the [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) function, that takes a `context` parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".lala").submit(function() {
        alert($("#textv", this).prev().val());
    });
});
```

This assumes that the browser does indeed build the object model with two elements having the same ID. If this does not work, try changing the selector in the line 3 to `input[type=text]`

Also, your code sample is missing a set of `});` in the end, but I guess this is just a copy/paste mistake made when posting the question.

Comment: this is not very friendly. if he wants to use an extra inputfield. working with selectors seems better to me

Comment: Sure, but considering the markup there is *nothing* to select on, apart from a duplicated `id` attribute.